# c++ MFC Update variable from Thread

Tags: c++, mfc

I want to update `line` variable from another Thread and draw it in void `CMFCApplicationUpdateUIView::OnDraw(CDC* pDC)`.

I have two problems:

first:

> 'CMFCApplicationUpdateUIDoc::Thread_no_1': non-standard syntax; use
>   '&' to create a pointer to member

second:

How to update `line` in `Thread_no_1` properly? What I need to use PostMessageW? Or?

**MFCApplicationUpdateUIDoc.h**

```
class CMFCApplicationUpdateUIDoc : public CDocument
{
public:
    virtual ~CMFCApplicationUpdateUIDoc();
    void StartCount();
    DWORD Thread_no_1(LPVOID lpParam);

};
```

**MFCApplicationUpdateUIDoc.cpp**

```
void CMFCApplicationUpdateUIDoc::StartCount()
{
    int Data_Of_Thread_1 = 1;
    HANDLE Handle_Of_Thread_1 = 0;
    Handle_Of_Thread_1 = CreateThread(NULL, 0, CMFCApplicationUpdateUIDoc::Thread_no_1, &Data_Of_Thread_1, 0, NULL);
    if (Handle_Of_Thread_1 == NULL)
        ExitProcess(Data_Of_Thread_1);
}

DWORD CMFCApplicationUpdateUIDoc::Thread_no_1(LPVOID lpParam)
{
    int     Data = 0;
    int     count = 0;
    HANDLE  hStdout = NULL;

    if ((hStdout = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE))== INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
        return 1;

    Data = *((int*)lpParam);

    for (count = 0; count <= 4; count++)
    {
        line = count;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**MFCApplicationUpdateUIView.cpp**

```
void CMFCApplicationUpdateUIView::OnDraw(CDC* pDC)
{
    CMFCApplicationUpdateUIDoc* pDoc = GetDocument();
    pDoc->StartCount();
    ASSERT_VALID(pDoc);
    if (!pDoc)
        return;

    CString str;
    str.Format(L"%d", pDoc->line);
    pDC->TextOutW(0, 0, str);
}
```

Comment: You are passing the address of `Data_Of_Thread_1` to the thread, but `Data_Of_Thread_1` is local to `CMFCApplicationUpdateUIDoc::StartCount()` and will go out of scope when `StartCount()` exits, leaving the thread with a dangling pointer to invalid memory since `StartCount()` does not wait for the thread to terminate before exiting.  Make `Data_of_Thread_1` be a class member instead. Also, you cannot use a non-static class method as the thread procedure for `CreateThread()`. You will have to change `Thread_no_1()` to be `static` and then pass the class's `this` pointer as the thread parameter.

Comment: The standard approach is to update the data of the document and then have the document notify all the views that there has been a change in the data and they need to update what they present.

Comment: See [MSDN Document/View Architecture](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4x1xy43a.aspx) as well as [3         The Document-View Architecture](http://www.cs.sjsu.edu/faculty/pearce/mfc/chp3/chapter3.htm) as well as [CodeProject Creating your first MFC Doc/View application](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/721/Creating-your-first-MFC-Doc-View-application).

Comment: Yet another incarnation of the phenomenon: *"Multithreading is the answer. What is the question?"* [Part 1](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/CppCon-2017/047) and [Part 2](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/CppCon-2017/052).